# How to optimize a select query in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm making a website that retrieves data from a table and displays it to the user. To do this I created a view on my Database that joins the main table "Historics" with other tables by id to get some columns names instead of the id. However, when I do "SELECT * FROM VIEW", the query never charges. I've tried to run it in the database, and it takes 16 minutes to retrieve approximately 4 millions of rows.

[image: time]
As you can notice I'm not an expert with SQL. I have tried to create Non-clustered indexes in the columns that I am using for the joins, and also I created one index for all of the columns at the same time, but none of this seems to work. (The indexes that I created are on the original table, not in the view)

Here is how I am creating the view. I select the columns that I want to show and then I make left outer joins to get the names of the columns by id.

```
DROP VIEW BIHistoricoEventos
GO
CREATE VIEW BIHistoricoEventos AS
SELECT        BI.HISTORICO_EVENTOS_CERRADOS.COD_EVE, 
              BI.HISTORICO_EVENTOS_CERRADOS.FEC_NOT, 
              BI.HISTORICO_EVENTOS_CERRADOS.SEMANA, 
              BI.HISTORICO_EVENTOS_CERRADOS.ANO, 
              BI.HISTORICO_EVENTOS_CERRADOS.COD_PRE, 
              BI.HISTORICO_EVENTOS_CERRADOS.COD_SUB, 
              BI.HISTORICO_EVENTOS_CERRADOS.COD_DPTO_O, 
              BI.HISTORICO_EVENTOS_CERRADOS.COD_MUN_O, 
              BI.HISTORICO_EVENTOS_CERRADOS.COD_ASE, 
              BI.HISTORICO_EVENTOS_CERRADOS.AJUSTE, 
              TipoEvento.nom_eve AS 'Nombre evento', Departamentos.Nom_dpto 
              AS 'Departamento', 
              Municipios.Nom_mun AS 'Municipio', 
              Ajustes.nombre AS 'Nombre Ajuste', Aseguradoras.Raz_soc AS 
              'Razon social aseguradora'
FROM         BI.HISTORICO_EVENTOS_CERRADOS LEFT OUTER JOIN
             Departamentos ON BI.HISTORICO_EVENTOS_CERRADOS.COD_DPTO_O = 
                  Departamentos.Cod_dpto LEFT OUTER JOIN
             Municipios ON CONCAT(BI.HISTORICO_EVENTOS_CERRADOS.COD_DPTO_O, 
                  BI.HISTORICO_EVENTOS_CERRADOS.COD_MUN_O)  = 
                  Municipios.Cod_mun LEFT OUTER JOIN 
             Aseguradoras ON BI.HISTORICO_EVENTOS_CERRADOS.COD_ASE = 
                  Aseguradoras.Cod_ase LEFT OUTER JOIN
             TipoEvento ON BI.HISTORICO_EVENTOS_CERRADOS.COD_EVE = 
                  TipoEvento.cod_eve LEFT OUTER JOIN 
             Ajustes ON  BI.HISTORICO_EVENTOS_CERRADOS.AJUSTE = 
                  SUBSTRING(Ajustes.nombre, 1, 1)
GO
```

I made indexes on each column present in the joins, but it still takes so long. 
I also don't know for sure if the indexes should be on the original table or on the view.

I would like to reduce the time that the query takes, I'm looking forward to your replies. Thank you.

EDIT: Here is the execution plan.. But currently I don't know how to optimize this. 
[image: exec plan]
Here is the link for the image https://i.ibb.co/NysYKVQ/execution-plan.png

Comment: Here's a hint - you probably don't need 4 millions rows of data to be returned in a single operation... How long is a page of your website going to be to display 4 million rows? :P

Comment: Sorry, we cannot read the sql when  it is a jpg.  Please paste in as a code fragment that is then surrounded by braces  { }

Comment: The page basically do aggregates, like in an OLAP cube but from a view, so I need it to do aggregates with all of the rows :(

Comment: Firstly - we would want to see a query plan, given you are joining on fields with concat's I doubt an index is helping you. Secondly, With 4 million rows - well you can calculate the disk space that has to be scanned + join operations, add in network time and depending on hardware, 16 minutes might not be that bad. I suspect on grabbing the plan we will see a lot of table scans / clustered index scans, and hash joins.

Comment: How many of these 4M rows will the user scroll thru?  What does the user really want???  There is NO aggregation happening in the sql; only the joining of 6 tables.

Comment: Not really to scroll, I am using pivotgrid by Telerik, so the user selects the aggregation criteria, and the columns and rows that wants to see, just as an OLAP cube. I would like for example to view events by location, how many for each city.

Comment: @Maga That is not *just like* an OLAP cube... if you need performance then use an OLAP cube, or perform the aggregations in your SQL query - retrieving all 4 million rows in full then operating on them is never going to be as fast

Comment: Please see [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for a better way to include an execution plan in your question.

Comment: Yeah like everyone says - 4 million rows to a webpage is madness! Besides that - you are using left hoins, they can be performance killers, and furthermore your joins are on concatted column values - goodbye indexes.
Update your table to have the keys - so you do not need concats in the joins, then you can index the join keys. Furthermore make sure you can do inner joins against the tables. Perhaps use dummy values - i don't know your data - but if you are ready to show it on a web page, you should have cleaned it beforehand, and not on the fly!

Comment: Oh - and you have no where clauses, why not materialize the table in your database, and have the webpage get the data directly from there? You can update the meterialization wheen needed or on a schedule

Answer (score 0):

look to execute a query of so many records is not good for the server and much less when rendering this in the view. What I would recommend is to execute a page and from the view you send the parameters to a stored procedure.

**You could take the following example:**

```
SELECT * FROM User ORDER BY 1 OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY;
```

**ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY:** is the limit of records that would be shown in the previous example would only show 20 records.

**OFFSET:** the group of records that would be shown. In the case of the previous example they would be shown from register 0 to 20 which is the limit of records.

In the following link, the different scenarios are shown a little more to use the results page. [link](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/01/t-sql-queries/pagination-with-offset-fetch)